# Stream a windowed application to another Windows PC on the LAN network?

Tags: windows, networking, streaming, webcam

I need to stream a single windowed application on a Windows 7 PC to another Windows PC, so that the other Windows PC can see that application and, preferably, interact with it. But all I want it to stream is that single application, not anything else.

I don't want any video lag on the program, and I don't want it to send it through the internet, just through LAN.

Is there any method I can use that meets those expectations (preferably free)? It's just that I'm using a camcorder that only plugs in with FireWire as a security camera that's meant to be hooked up to my server PC, but only my gaming PC has a FireWire port, so I thought the least money-consuming idea would be to run the Webcam Recorder app on my gaming PC and stream the application to my server PC.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic here because it is "_asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation_" which is specifically off-topic. Maybe you should ask the question on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

[TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com) can do this.  One of its many features is to share just an application, as opposed to the entire desktop.

Comment: Yes, except it doesn't stream through LAN though, it streams through the TeamViewer servers/the internet

Comment: And it's not free

Comment: it is absolutely free

Comment: and it has LAN streaming.    it does everything you wanted for free

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the answers to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226772/can-rdp-clients-launch-remote-applications-and-not-desktops

The built in RemoteDesktop functionality of Windows has functionality that covers your use case.